# Create sources jar for shrunk classes in a module via proguard

Tags: java, maven, proguard

There is a business module - say `kilo-business` in one of the applications. Now there are some APIs in this module that is to be used by another application (locally within the organization - say `kilo-client1`). I have used Proguard (via its maven plugin) to only extract the classes relevant to the API and make a JAR out of it - the shrunk API JAR called `kilo-business-apis`. `kilo-client1` uses this `kilo-business-apis` dependency and invokes the service. As a policy, we always include sources along with any artifact that we share between applications (for debugging ease and additional documentation).

In this case, is there a way that one can have Proguard also give out the (probable) source files (belonging to `kilo-business` module) from where it has sourced the classes for the `kilo-business-apis` using which a sources JAR can be conjured? Actually, we don't shrink the JAR to the extent of removing unused methods/variables from the class, so giving out the source java files would also suffice.

I understand that one can use jd-eclipse or some other decompiler in eclipse to aid debugging even if we don't publish it, but wanted to check if we can generate the sources first class whereby documentation needs are also addressed.

One thought is to break up `kilo-business` itself into a separate module for `kilo-business-apis` where only the API definitions reside and both `kilo-business` and `kilo-client1` can use it, but unfortunately I can't do it for legacy reasons.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProGuard optionally writes out information about kept entry points (-printseeds), unused code (-printusage), and obfuscation mapping (-printmapping), but nothing related to source files. If you don't obfuscate the code, you can simply list the .class names in the processed output, and find the corresponding .java files.